# How to solve for $x$ in $x^3+8^x-9=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to find real numbers $x$ that are solutions to
$$x^3+8^x-9=0$$
Please help me.

Comment: Another hint to go along with BMS's answer, look at a plot of the function, for example, using [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bx%5E3%2B8%5Ex+-+9%2C+%7Bx%2C-2%2C2%7D%5D). Regards

Comment: One more suggestion: many problems of this type (not all, of course) can be solved for $x$ using Lambert-W function (see Wiki entry on examples), but this is not a 'closed-form' solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## $$(x^3 -1)=(8-8^x) $$

## $$(x-1)\color{Violet}{(x^2 +x+1)}= (8-8^x )$$

## $$But\color{Violet} {(x^2+x+1)>0}$$

## $$Eithr\color{blue}{  (x-1)\geq0} \space\space and\space \color{red}{8-8^x\geq0}$$

## $$\color{blue}{x\geq1}\space and \space \color{red}{x\leq1} \Rightarrow\space \color{green} {x=1}$$

## $$OR\color{blue}{  (x-1)\leq0} \space\space and\space \color{red}{8-8^x\leq0}$$

## $$\color{blue}{x\leq1}\space and \space \color{red}{x\geq1} \Rightarrow\space \color{green} {x=1}$$

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: Nice solution +1

Answer (score 8):

HINT: Try a few small whole numbers, and you’ll quickly find a solution. Note also that $x^3+8^x$ is an increasing function of $x$, so there can be at most one solution.

Comment: yes i found  x=1 but i want  Algebraic solution

Comment: @FashfeeshFood: I’d be surprised if there were one. I’d be **very** much surprised if there were a straightforward one.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align}
x^3+8^x-9=0\iff
&
\begin{cases}
x^3-1=2^3-(2^{x})^3\\
x^3-8=1^3-(2^{x})^3\\
\end{cases}
\\
\iff 
&
\begin{cases}
(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=[2-(2^{x})][2^2+2(2^{x}) + (2^{x})^2] \\
(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)=[1-(2^{x})][1+(2^{x})+(2^{x})^2] \\
\end{cases}
\\
\end{align}
Then is easy to see that $x=1 \implies x^3+8^x-9=0 $.

We have that $f(x)=x^3+8^x-9\implies f^\prime(x)=3x^2+e^x\cdot\log_e(8)>0$ and then $f(x)$ have only one root. That is, $f(x)=0\implies x=1$.

Then $x=1$ the unique root.